# How to ask HomePod to play a specific stream

Tags: siri, streaming, homepod

I would like my HomePod (2nd gen.) to play this specific stream: Calm by Classical King FM radio.

Quoting their [their web site](https://king.org/listen#other-ways):

> **Smart Speakers**
>
> To access Classical KING on your smart speaker, use the following command: “___, play Classical KING ”.
>
> To access the Classical Calm streaming channel, use the following command: "___, play Calm by Classical KING"

I have been saying "Hey Siri, play Calm by Classical King". I get all kinds of musical choices by Siri, but I never get that stream.

I do have the latest version of firmware installed on the HomePod, per iOS 17.2 on my iPhone.

Any tips on how to adapt those instructions specifically for Siri on a HomePod?